# I can't read onnx with opencv on window11

Tags: python, opencv, yolo, onnx

I exported yolov6 pytorch model as onnx. However, opencv can't read it on Window 11. I think its not onnx model's problem, because it worked well on colab, WSL.

I exported my custom torch model as onnx

```
#YOLOv6 directory
deploy/ONNX/export_onnx.py --weights runs/train/exp2/weights/best_ckpt.pt --device 0
```

load onnx with opencv

```
import cv2
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromONNX('runs/train/exp2/weights/best_ckpt.onnx')
```

Then I got heap corruption error.

```
Process finished with exit code -1073740940 (0xC0000374)
```

python version is 3.10.11 and pip list is below.

```
Package                 Version
----------------------- --------------------
absl-py                 2.0.0
addict                  2.4.0
cachetools              5.3.2
certifi                 2023.7.22
charset-normalizer      3.3.2
colorama                0.4.6
contourpy               1.2.0
cycler                  0.12.1
filelock                3.13.1
fonttools               4.44.0
fsspec                  2023.10.0
google-auth             2.23.4
google-auth-oauthlib    1.1.0
grpcio                  1.59.2
idna                    3.4
importlib-metadata      6.8.0
importlib-resources     6.1.0
Jinja2                  3.1.2
kiwisolver              1.4.5
Markdown                3.5.1
markdown-it-py          3.0.0
MarkupSafe              2.1.3
matplotlib              3.8.1
mdurl                   0.1.2
mpmath                  1.3.0
networkx                3.2.1
numpy                   1.26.1
oauthlib                3.2.2
onnx                    1.15.0
onnx-simplifier         0.4.35
opencv-python           4.8.1.78
packaging               23.2
Pillow                  10.1.0
pip                     20.2.3
protobuf                4.23.4
psutil                  5.9.6
pyasn1                  0.5.0
pyasn1-modules          0.3.0
pycocotools             2.0.7
Pygments                2.16.1
pyparsing               3.1.1
python-dateutil         2.8.2
PyYAML                  6.0.1
requests                2.31.0
requests-oauthlib       1.3.1
rich                    13.6.0
rsa                     4.9
scipy                   1.11.3
setuptools              49.2.1
six                     1.16.0
sympy                   1.12
tensorboard             2.15.1
tensorboard-data-server 0.7.2
thop                    0.1.1.post2209072238
torch                   2.1.0+cu121
torchvision             0.16.0
tqdm                    4.66.1
typing-extensions       4.8.0
urllib3                 2.0.7
werkzeug                3.0.1
zipp                    3.17.0
```

Comment: I chose Csharp instead solving this problem.